# Passing text containing linebreaks as command or environment parameter?

Tags: line-breaking, conditionals, parameters

I just tried to write some commands which used its argument to check whether they were empty (`isempty{...}` from package `ifthen`) or not. The problem was that the text to check contained a linebreak, and that screwed up the whole system and caused it to produce very strange error messages.

Is there a way to work around this and make it safe to pass text containing linebreaks as parameter to a command or environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `etextools` package provides an expandable `\ifempty{<text>}{<true>}{<false>}` macro which works with newlines.

If you don't need the test to be expandable you can also use the following code:

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{%
   \begingroup
   \def\temp{#1}%
   \ifx\temp\empty
      \endgroup
       % empty
   \else
      \endgroup
       % not empty
   \fi
}
```

Comment: Why do you work with `begingroup` ... `endgroup` ?

Comment: @Macro: to make `\temp` local

Comment: @Macro: As Leo already said, it is to make the assignment to `\temp` local, which is generally a good design decision.

Comment: @Leo: I can't understand the background. `\def` works only inside `\mymacro`. During the writing of this comment I think the attention is to use `\temp` once more inside `\mymacro`. EDIT: Thanks Martin

Comment: @Macro: If you use several such macros uses `\temp` nestly, it is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

The \isempty test expands its argument; you may try

```
\ifthenelse{\isempty{\unexpanded{#1}}}{<true>}{<false>}
```

or resort to a different test like

```
\ifx\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  <true>%
\else
  <false>%
\fi
```

In both cases `#1` stands for the argument you want to test.